# Confused about where to manage my "job alerts"

Tags: support, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

After you create a job alert, the system states

## THANKS

But then where are these alerts managed, in addition, how do I manage my alerts after I've created them.  Is this somewhere tucked away and I'm just missing it?  It isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your job alerts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts).

Comment: Great, thanks, look forward to the re-design!

Comment: Link is now dead

Answer (score 3):

[Jason's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312739/193619) alludes to a future update. In the meantime, here's the URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts

(The link is included at the bottom of the alert emails.)